# Java dealing with exceptions appropriately

Tags: java, exception

not that familiar with JAVA or exception handling. Looking for some advice on what is acceptable and what is frowned upon.

The scenario, i'm building a game of life program, I have conditionals set up to check if a cell will be out of bounds and not try to access that 'cell'. My question is, is it acceptable to use a try catch block instead of 8 conditionals, and just do nothing if the arrayOutOfBounds exception is thrown. ie ignore the cells out of bounds, or is this bad practice? for instance...

```
try{
    neighbors += cellIsAlive(row, col);
}catch(ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException e)
{
    //dont do anything and continue counting neighbors
}
```

In this scenario cellIsAlive method checks a location in a multi dimensional array and returns 1 if it's alive 0 otherwise and throws ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException.

Is this a good idea or is it bad practice to use exceptions this way?

Thanks ahead of time for any input.

Comment: haha sorry, my php coming out. will edit.

Comment: *Exceptions* were made to handle... *exceptions*. But since you can know the problem, it's better for you to simply check the indexes..

Comment: you should never swallow an exception, you simply don't!

Comment: @ Maroun I was thinking that, but it seems like this would greatly simplify the code and make it more readable,like I said I'm not that experienced in this situation. Seems like everyone agrees the conditionals are better though.

Comment: In general, using exceptions to control program flow is frowned upon because it's normally much cheaper to check bounds than it is to create and then catch the exception (though I believe that cost has come down as the JVM has evolved).

Comment: @NickHolt thanks, your comment is more of an explanation than any of the answers so far. Thanks for an explanation.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a php developer. the dollar sign before a variable comes naturally. It's changed now though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's absolutely a bad practice. Exception handling consumes a lot of resources and should be used only (as its name implies) for exceptional cases.

Take a look at chapter 9 of this book (and also read the rest when you can):

[http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-Edition-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)

You'll see that what you're trying to do is very similar to the example used for illustrating what you're not supposed to do, and I quote:

> Someday, if you are unlucky, you may stumble across a piece of code
>   that looks something like this:

```
// Horrible abuse of exceptions. Don't ever do this!
try {
    int i = 0;
    while(true)
        range[i++].climb();
} catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
}
```

> What does this code do? It’s not at all obvious from inspection, and
>   that’s reason enough not to use it (Item 55). It turns out to be a
>   horribly ill-conceived idiom for looping through the elements of an
>   array.

Comment: Thanks, both for the information and the book reccomendation.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bad practice to catch `RuntimeExcepions`. `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException` is a subclass of `RuntimeException`. `RuntimeExceptions` are programmers fault, You should catch only checked Exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Catching ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException wont help you andcatching runtime exceptions is a bad habbit .
Fix the logic inside cellIsActive() method ..

Use http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm for more details